# Can modern cameras (BMCC, Red, Arri, etc) record to a drive over ad-hoc wifi?

Tags: production, storage, wireless, red

Is there a solution that bifurcates drives and camera bodies?

At first glance it seems feasible that camera bodies could be equipped with 802.11ac mimo and transmit the raw image data to a drive at a DIT workstation.

Is there any tech hurdle in making this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Any camera with an HDMI or SDI output can can stream via wifi using a Teradek Cube (http://teradek.com/pages/cube).

This setup will allow you to monitor and record via iOS or computer. It also supports remote recording over the internet (decoder needed).

In addition to WiFi, Terdek also supports 3G/4G/LTE cellular networks via a USB modem.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Eyefi product line which basically wraps a small wifi chip together with a small arm SoC into an SD package with some limited internal storage.
http://www.eyefi.com/products/prox2

They do work but the range is rather limited and you have to use their software in order to use them. Also only SD cards in their product line which aren't used in most mid/high-end DSLRs.
The SPI bus used by SD cards makes this whole thing quite a lot easier than with the old CompacFlash interface. Though the CompacFlash interface can act as a small form factor version of the old P-ATA.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompactFlash#Technical_details

In theory it's not all too hard to make and adapter with off the shelf parts, there is a huge discussion about this on this forum: http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=5470.350

It seems they never came to any solution but then again most of them are technology enthusiastic photographers. You will need some knowledge about electrical engineering to pull this off.

EDIT: Seems there are adapters for SD to CF:

Comment: Note that it does not stream data live, but rather allows remote access to the file after it is done writing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main concern would be reliability of the connection and lag.  The potential buffering issues could be a concern based on being a generic data connection.

There are existing specialized solutions for sending uncompressed video data wirelessly though, so wireless data transmission is possible, wifi may not be the ideal technology to do it though.